# Normal-Normal mixture model for variance hyperparameter

Tags: normal-distribution, inference, hierarchical-bayesian, hyperparameter

Consider the product of two Normal distributions (prior-hyperprior):
$$
p(\sigma^2) \propto \mathcal{N}(\theta; 0, s^2 \tau^2 \sigma^2)\mathcal{N}(\sigma^2; 0, c^2 \gamma^2)
$$
this is a scale mixture of normals with normal mixing density for the variance term $\sigma^2$. More often, we find a solution when the normal hyperprior is assigned to the mean not the variance. Assuming that the means are zero and ommiting the fact that normals *are not the usual* hyperpriors for variance hyperparameters, is there a closed form solution for the mentioned product?

Thanks in advance!